# Sorting a vector of vector ints

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector of vectors that include pairs and i want to sort them on the basis that the divided result between the pair is the deciding sorting factor.

```
vector<vector<int>> = {{1,2},{1,3},{2,5}};
```

1/2 = 0.5 and 1/3 = 0.333 and 2/5 = 0.4 therefore it should sort like the following:

```
{1,3},{2,5},{1,2}
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: ```std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());```

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort` accepts a custom predicate. So you can define a lambda here that does your comparison:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myvec = {{1,2},{1,3},{2,5}};
std::sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 
    [](const auto& v1, const auto& v2) { return (v1.at(0)*v2.at(1)) < v2.at(0)*v1.at(1); }
);
```

You'd have to make sure that all the inner vector contain at least two elements. Probably a `std::pair` would fit better here

Comment: There is no need for division; `(v1.at(0)/v1.at(1)) < v2.at(0)/v2.at(1)` can be replaced with `(v1.at(0) * v2.at(1)) < v2.at(0) * v1.at(1)`. Those are ints, and the OP's question doesn't expect integer division.

Comment: @Stef correct, I edited my answer.

Comment: I like this solution however i got an out of range error.

Comment: @GeorgeKhanachat Are you **sure** that your vector contains only vectors which have exactly two elements?

Comment: Yeah, 100% sure

Comment: @GeorgeKhanachat, Use `vector<std::pair<>>` rather than `vector<vector<>>`, and you won't get range error.